# Python building 2d array getting list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

```
N = len(s1)
M = len(s2)
matrix = [[0 for i in range(N+1)] for j in range(M+1)]
gap = int(raw_input('Enter gap score'))
mismatch = int(raw_input('Enter mismatch score'))
match = int(raw_input('Enter the match score'))

matrix[0][0] = 0

for i in range(1,(N+1)):
    matrix[i][0]=(matrix[(i-1)][0] + gap)

for j in range(1,(M+1)):
    matrix[0][j]=(matrix[0][(j-1)] + gap)  

for i in range(1,N+1):
    for j in range(1,M+1):
        if(s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]):
            score1 = matrix[i-1][j-1] + match

        else:
            score1 = matrix[i-1][j-1] + mismatch

        score2 = matrix[i][j-1] + gap
        score3 = matrix[i-1][j] + gap
        matrix[i][j] = max(score1, score2, score3)
```

I get the error code 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matt\workspace\ch3skills\ch3skills.py", line 67, in 
    matrix[0][j]=(matrix[0][(j-1)] + gap)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: Maybe `matrix[0][M]` doesn't exist?

Comment: It should because it's created matrix = [[0 for i in range(N+1)] for j in range(M+1)] however if I flip the N and M around in the for loops it works just fine. That throws off the rest of the program though

Comment: `len(matrix[0])` is N+1 not M+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with defining the matrix. If N and M are same you will not get an error. With different N and M values you find the error. Consider the case for N=1 and M=2 your matrix is [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]. Now consider this bit of code:
    for i in range(1,(M+1)):
        matrix[i][0]=(matrix[(i-1)][0] + gap)
In case you have i with values 1 to 3, but you don't have matrix[3][0]. This gives such an error. I cannot understand what is code is intended to do. Now changing M and N i don't get any further errors. But i am not sure whether you are looking for this. I will include the code also.

```
s1 = raw_input('1: ')
s2 = raw_input('2: ')
N = len(s1)
M = len(s2)
matrix = [[0 for i in range(N+1)] for j in range(M+1)]
gap = int(raw_input('Enter gap score'))
mismatch = int(raw_input('Enter mismatch score'))
match = int(raw_input('Enter the match score'))

matrix[0][0] = 0

for i in range(1,(M+1)):
    matrix[i][0]=(matrix[(i-1)][0] + gap)

for j in range(1,(N+1)):
    matrix[0][j]=(matrix[0][(j-1)] + gap)  

for i in range(1,M+1):
    for j in range(1,N+1):
        if(s1[j-1] == s2[i-1]):
            score1 = matrix[i-1][j-1] + match

        else:
            score1 = matrix[i-1][j-1] + mismatch

        score2 = matrix[i][j-1] + gap
        score3 = matrix[i-1][j] + gap
        matrix[i][j] = max(score1, score2, score3)
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that I had to switch them when creating the 2d array. However the for loops do not have to be changed. But thanks for the information on why switching them when making the 2d array worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch `M` and `N` in your `for` loops, like this:

```
for i in range(1,M+1):
    matrix[i][0] = matrix[i-1][0] + gap

for j in range(1,N+1):
    matrix[0][j] = matrix[0][j-1] + gap
```

Since you initially make `M` items, each being a list of length `N`, `matrix[x]` is the xth list (of length `N`).

Also: 1) all those parentheses add too much clutter; 2) numpy would make all of this much easier.